# Send array from javascript to php by POST in Joomla 3.x

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, javascript, jquery

im trying to send an array from javascript to Joomla 3.x php file.

```
var options = ['foo', 'bar'];

$.post('index.php?option=component&view=componentview&Itemid=123&tmpl=component&layout=xlsx', {'xlsx_options': options})
```

Then, I have a php file which creates data in order to download xlsx file. But I need to filter by this options array and Im not able to retrieve it. I've tried this without success.

```
$xlsx = $_POST['xlsx_options'];
$xlsx = json_decode($_POST['xlsx_options'], true);
$xlsx = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('xlsx_options');
```

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Do you need anymore help or was Lodder's answer the right one for you?

Comment: @Mark your question appears to be abandoned.  If Lodder's answer solved your issue please award it the green tick.  If there is still something to resolve, please leave a comment under the answer to isolate what is not yet right.  Marking an accepted answer not only rewards the volunteer who best helps you, it signifies to future researchers that the answer indeed solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You firstly need to encode your array in Javascript, like so:

```
var options = JSON.stringify(['foo', 'bar']);

$.post('index.php?option=component&view=componentview&Itemid=123&tmpl=component&layout=xlsx&options=' + options);
```

Then in your PHP code, use the following instead of `$_POST`:

```
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$xlsx  = json_decode($input->get('xlsx_options'));

echo $xlsx->foo;
echo $xlsx->bar;
```

Comment: Is it recommended to specify `->post()` for this question?